# sqoop export failing due to timeout

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I am not able to export data from sqoop to as400 server.

I am able to import the data successfully.

I am using following command: –

```
sqoop export –driver com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver –connect jdbc:as400://178.xxx.3.21:23/MELLET1/TEXT4 –username xxxxxx –password xxxxx007 –table TEXT3 –export-dir /as400/1GBTBL5/part-m-00000 -m 1
```

I am getting timeout issue.

```
>15/05/10 17:42:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/10 17:42:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/05/10 17:42:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/05/10 17:42:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:     job_1431267418859_0014
15/05/10 17:42:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application   application_1431267418859_0014
15/05/10 17:42:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1431267418859_0014
15/05/10 17:42:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1431267418859_0014 running in  uber mode : false
15/05/10 17:42:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:42:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:47:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :  attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_0 Timed out after 300 secs
15/05/10 17:47:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:48:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:53:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :  attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_1 Timed out after 300 secs
15/05/10 17:53:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:53:40 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0%
15/05/10 17:58:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :  attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
AttemptID:attempt_1431267418859_0014_m_000000_2 Timed out after 300 secs
```

Comment: Please remove your personal information from query

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below command which is for MySQL, similarly you can frame to your database accordingly

```
$ sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/foo --table bar --export-dir /results/bar_data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but there is no syntax error in command that i used for export. I am getting timeout. No other error. will you please help me other than syntax thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried batch mode?

```
set -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement and --batch
```